# Drupal 6 website is very slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've made [this website](http://www.heuvelfolies.be/) for someone a while ago, using Drupal 6. The problem is that it's getting incredibly slow... When I optimize the database it seems to go faster for a while and then it's slow again... I tried almost everything that I found on Google, and nothing seems to work. Maybe someone here knows a bit more than Google? :p

Comment: The aggresive cahcing method seems to have improved loading time by a ton... But does anyone happen to know how your can set teh cache expiration higher than 1 day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed using [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), is that some of your images on this page (http://heuvelfolies.be/CMS/Producten) are resized using HTML and CSS, rather than displaying thumbnails.  Not related to your db issues, but overall it will help with page loading.

Example output:
http://heuvelfolies.be/img/Producten_Netten.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 360x360 to 100x100. Serving a scaled image could save 74.7KiB (92% reduction)

Are you using other caching techniques such as Memcached?  Drupal caching would be step one, which you mentioned you did, but the next step would be an intermediate caching system.  I've had great luck with it. 
**UPDATE:** Doesn't look like your host provides VPS so this would be something to do if you ever moved to a VPS. Having said that, being on a shared server has its limitations.  Not knowing what the "other guys" on the server are running that may be slowing the whole thing down, is one of those limitations.

Comment: Page speed cant identity any Database related issues. So not very much relevant to Drupal.

Comment: site speed can be related to other things.  As you'll notice from the OP comment a year and a half ago, caching has improved loading time a ton.

Answer (score 1):

- Are you using Drupal's built-in caching?
  If not, turn it on -- it can make a big difference.
  You may also want to look into a server-based caching solution such as Varnish.
- What modules are you using?
  It's possible that you're using a module with known issues. Google for speed problems related to the various modules you're using.
- Are you displaying any dynamic content on every page?
  This can slow things down, as dynamic pages can't be cached. Consider using AHAH or AJAX to load the dynamic parts of the page via Javascript after page load, so they are separated from the main page content, which you can then cache properly.

Comment: Caching an merging of scripts and style sheets are enabled. I'm only using the modules I absolutely need.Dynamic content? Absolutely none. There's one page that absolutely always needs to be up-to-date. The other ones probably won't change for another year or so.

Comment: @RobinJ - Do your users log in to the site? Drupal's caching only operates when the user is not logged in

Answer (score 0):

I can't event ping that server. Maybe you should consider changing a hosting?

Other things worth checking are cache enabled, JS and CSS file merging enabled. If layout consists of many graphics, consider using CSS sprite. Also make sure that connection to your DB is fast.

Comment: `Other things worth checking are cache enabled, JS and CSS file merging enabled.` Already enabled. And the problem isn't the loading... it's the page generation that seems to be slow...

Comment: ... Goddamnit... the server seems to be down right now. So I can't really show you what's the problem >.<

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to improve anything, check the "Recent Log Entries" on the admin page.

There are so many reasons for a site being slow, first try to make sure that there's no errors.

I've just had a look at your site, it wasn't particularly slow, nor fast. Pages didn't seem to hang but thumbnails were not loading so quickly.

Check your site's health, check your hosting provider, look into caching, for solutions like Varnish, you will need Pressflow or Drupal 7 as well as root access, meaning at least a VPS...

Comment: Yeah for some reason it's pretty fast at the moment. Probably less traffic just after the downtime. However, the admin page is still, as always, loading slow as hell >.<

Comment: What type of hosting do you have? on a side note, you should really avoid putting an email address on the site, you're too nice with the spam bots!

Comment: One.com 3GB pack. It's not my website btw. I made it for someone else. No spam so far :p

Comment: You're on the grid, meaning that your site's performance will be affected by other users... any results on the Log Entries?

Comment: ... The logs and warnings option in the admin panel? Wel... When I click that I see a normal page with a title..... and no content appart from that. I do see the menus and headers and stuff like that. Only the "logs and warnings" are missing :p